# How can I get the coordinates of a clicked mouse (I need math calculation only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I have a box with a width of 800 and height of 600.

Then my screen size (container) is 1000 and its height is 700.

then, if we say:

```
x = container
y = rectangle
z = point in space
```

The engine only outputs the z based on its coordinate in `x`, therefore I need to calculate the coordinate of `z` in `y`.

I have:

```
z
size of x
size of y
coordinate of z in x
```

and what I want?

coordinate of `z` in `y`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Click for Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/755Hr/1/)

### Jquery

```
  $("#id").click(function(e){
       var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
       //or $(this).offset(); if you really just want the current element's offset
       var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
       var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
    });
```

### Html

```
<div id="id">
           //or $(this).offset(); if you really just want the current element's offset
</div>
```

Comment: I will check it and if it works I accept it as answer, already votted up thanks..

Comment: Is it okay want anything else

Answer (score 1):

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/2Fnwt/10/)

It gives co-ordinates only for related container

Here is Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#container").click(function(e){
   alert(e.pageX - $("#container").parent().offset().left);
    alert( e.pageY - $("#container").parent().offset().top);
 });
});
```